# Kubernetes: CPU Resource allocation for POD

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to assign CPU resources for services running in kubernetes pods. Services are mostly nodejs based REST endpoints with some DB operations.

During the load test, tried different combinations between 100m and 1000m for pods. 
For the expected number of requests/second, when value is less than < 500m more pods are getting spawned as part of HPA  than when the value is >500m. I am using CPU based trigger for HPA.

I couldn't figure out depending on what I shall be selecting particular CPU resource value. Can someone help me in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

Two points:

1. If you configured the HPA to autoscale based on CPU utilisation, it makes sense that there are more replicas if the CPU request is 500m than if it's 1000m. This is because the target utilisation that you define for the HPA is relative to the CPU request of the Pods.

   For example, if your target utilisation is 80% and the CPU request of the Pods is 500m, then the HPA scales your app up if the actual CPU usage exceeds 400m. On the other hand, if the CPU requests are 1000m, then the HPA only scales up if the CPU usage exceeds 800m.
2. Selecting resource requests (e.g. CPU) for a container is very important, but it's also an art in itself. The CPU is the minimum amount of CPU that your container needs for running reliably. What you could do to find out this value is running your app locally and try to evaluate how much CPU it is actually using, for example, with `ps` or `top`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yeah, I figured out that its an art. :) 
I am confused about how many simultaneous requests one particular pod should be handling at any point of time. And what decides that value.

Comment: It requires some experimentation and load testing if you really want to find out an appropriate value.

Comment: Yes, I did experiment. 
At steady state, each pod is serving about say X requests/second when CPU configured with XC. And  each pod is serving about say Y requests/second when CPU configured with YC. I also figured out that "depended" pods when placed on same node, is causing entire node CPU go up as the request rate goes up. I am not sure about placement of PODS either.

Comment: The CPU request of each Pod is used by the scheduler to decide what node to place a Pod on. For example, if you have a node with 2 free CPU cores and the CPU request of your Pods is 500m, then the scheduler may place 4 of these Pods on this node. On the other hand, if the CPU request of the Pods is 1000m, then the scheduler will at most place 2 of these Pods on this node.

Comment: But the CPU request of a Pod shouldn't directly influence how many requests your app serves per second. It's only used by the scheduler to decide where to place the nodes. If it has an effect on your request rate, it could only be the case if a Pod exceeds its _CPU limit_ (this is different from _CPU request_), in which case the Pod gets throttled.

Comment: Let me will explain what I did. I used 200m as _CPU request_ for all my services, I had about 15 services.  Then scheduler placed few of the dependent pods in one Node. When I started load testing _without rampup_, one node showed high CPU. When I continued with increasing the load, some depended pods in that node went to _evicted_ state. 
When I used  600m, not all dependent pods got into the same node. I continued the same test with more nodes. Obviously it served more requests/second. I have different services with different average requests/second.